# Auto Login primary user account

Tags: login

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I have been searching and searching with no luck on how to successfully have my primary user account to auto-login immediately after computer boots.

I have already enabled automatic login under settings ---> Details -----> Users
I also see these lines of code in `/etc/gddm3/custom.conf` saying that it is enabled

[image]

But after I reboot my computer, i have to click on my user and type my password.

Please Help and Thank you!

Comment: You should make it from user accounts GUI page

Comment: I have also done that

Comment: How many users do you have?

Comment: just the one user

Comment: I have found when i change password to something more complicated (includes a period and more characters), auto login does not work.... weird

Comment: Is the Language single 0r multiple??

Comment: single language

Comment: I think the approach you shown may be not the perfect way.. Can you try different approach by searching in Askubuntu.com for Auto login for GNOME gdm3